# Filter the grid data is not working in FF(mozilla) and IE

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am working with kendo ui controls.my functionality is to filter the grid based on date-time and drop down selection. This is working on chrome but not in FF and IE.

```
                var gridResult = $('#Grid').data("kendoGrid");

                    var condition = {
                        logic: "and",
                        filters: [
                            { field: "Category", operator: "equals", value: $("#nw").val() },
                            { field: "Device", operator: "equals", value: $("#pro").val() },
                            { field: "Orig", operator: "equals", value: $("#work").val() },
                            { field: "Term", operator: "equals", value: $("#network").val() }
                        ]
                    };
                    if (mindate !== null) {
                        condition.filters.push({ field: "Time", operator: "ge", value: new Date(mindate) });
                    }
                    if (maxdate !== null) {
                        maxdate = new Date(maxdate);
                        maxdate.setHours(23, 59, 59, 999);
                        condition.filters.push({ field: "Time", operator: "lt", value: maxdate });
                    }
                    gridResult.dataSource.filter(condition);

                return false;
            });

        $('#fromdatetimepicker').attr('readonly', false);
        $('#todatetimepicker').attr('readonly', false);
      }
```

When i debug in firefox i didn't find aby bug can any one look at the code and please tell me where i am wrong?

Comment: things to check, page html end tags, FF and IE tend to be more similar here, page load complete, semi-colon insertion, event propagation, the return false in your on-click handler might change that.

Comment: hi thank you for reply, page html end tags is not in proper it shows error but i am not getting any error.how could i find that?

Answer (score 0):

I've been testing your code and I can't find any problems with it, besides that you have an extra `)` at the end but that's probably because the function is cut from a larger section of code.

There are however several things that might be causing this problem and there's a lot of code missing so I can't say for sure. Some browsers try to help you out by ignoring errors you make. This can make it work in Chrome but not in FF and IE. The best way to deal with this is to go through the code and add validations that confirm the values every time the Filter method is call. Here are my suggestions for you:

- When debugging in Internet Explorer, use IE 11 and use the F12 debugging tool.
- You check that `mindate` and `maxdate` are not null, but if they're `undefined` or contain an empty value, they'll pass that test and will be added to the filters even though they're not set.
- You don't have any check that `mindate` and `maxdate` are valid dates and that you successfully are able to create the JavaScript `date` variable, before adding it to the filter. This could be a source of error, depending on the other code in your script.
- You use the values from `$("#network").val()` etc directly in your filter without validating them, and that could cause problems in the future. But this is not causing this error.

**Edit: Encoding**

You need to make sure the encoding of your webpage is correct. Please make sure these two lines exist in the `head` section of the `html` code. If you use ASP.NET MVC you can add these two files to the `Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml` file. If you use ASP.NET Forms you can add them in your Masterfile. If you use PHP you just put them in the `head` section.

```
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
```

Comment: ok Ohlin i give my total "clear button" code with validation can please check it once.i will edit code.

Comment: Can you give a better explanation on what it is that doesn't work. Doesn't anything work or? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: Iin my project i had one grid for filter the data using two kendodatetimepicker and 4 kendodropdownlist.while filter in chrome with above code is working fine but not in IE and FF

Comment: hi Ohlini, explained above, is that satisfactory? Just let me know if you need more explanation on this functionality.

Comment: here is the error i got error:The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.
http://localhost:81/max.html
Line 0

Comment: Hi @Sandeep. That error message was very helpful and I've updated my answer with info on how to set character encoding in your HTML document. If it doesn't work then please let me know.

Comment: hi i had one one doubt that here i am using only kenodcontrols in plain html page with IDE visualstudio .i didnt use any asp.net mvc or php. and previously my meta tag is <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10" /> and i got this error in mozilla

Comment: in the this fiddle filter is not working in IE but working in FF i just used the those url but still not working http://jsbin.com/etuguq/1/edit

Comment: Your fiddle works just fine for me both in Chrome, IE and FF. In IE I have to click on the little arrow up in the right corner (Live Preview) so I get the output in a new Window. IE doesn't show the grid in the combined window but it works fine in Live Preview mode. I've tested in both IE10 and IE11.

Comment: k ohlin sorry for that that's not my code i just given sample fiddle to is that my problem.but when i used same kendo url for my project than also it's not working.

Comment: I'm sorry. I've tried your code over and over and it works just fine for me in all browsers. You need to provide with a COMPLETE code (all the HTML code) or I can't do anything more for you...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37158/discussion-between-sandeep-and-ohlin)